# How can I fix the broken edge flipping feature?

Tags: unity, 11.10

Since Unity was used on Ubuntu 11.04 Beta, this problem has been distubbing me for a long time.
Yesterday I found the bug report and try to get it well, but still there's one problem.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/771448?comments=all
I did as the post told in #6, edge fliping works well at first.
Later I found every time I reboot, the edge flipging at Top will not work.
After I ran "compiz --replace", it worked in the right way.
I checked that report again, without seeing a better solution.
So how can I deal with that problem?

Comment: Add `compiz --replace` to the startup applications maybe? (Until a real solution comes along)

Comment: According to the FAQ this question is not valid, beta is beta, there is a reason its called beta, its not finished! You just will have to wait for the bug to be solved or add `compiz --replace` as suggested to your start up (make a script for it) ;) Gl and hope this can be fixed for you soon.

Answer (score 1):

According to the FAQ this question is not valid, beta is beta, there is a reason its called beta, its not finished! You just will have to wait for the bug to be solved or add `unity --replace` as suggested to your start up (or add it to any startup script you might have) ;)

If you want to add it to a script on your start up programs search for the program `Startup Applications`.

Save this (or add it to your startup script) on your home folder or somewhere you have permitions:

```
#! /bin/bash
unity --replace
```

you will need to use `chmod 755 <nameofthescript.sh>` to make it executable. Add the scrip to the `Startup Applications` list and that should be able to fix it until a new package comes.

If you dont have a startup script just add `unity --replace` to your start up applications list.

Comment: Why not just put `compiz --replace` in startup applications? Why write a script for it?

Comment: @oli because we love [Rube Goldberg machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine)!

Comment: Side note: brunopereira81, it's `unity --replace` not `compiz --replace`. You always replace `unity`, not `compiz` - at least when you're dealing with something like this.

Comment: I like scripts?

Comment: Scripts break/get overwritten/lost/etc - if you lose a login command, you've got other problems. :)

Comment: Oh well, I just have a scrip for the tweaks I need, like opening Boxee on my big ass Tv automatically, why add a lot of items on your startup programs if you can have 1 script that does all for you? dunno, still its a valid argument, your wish will be complied.

Comment: There's a protip for that too. You can run multiple things from one Startup Applications entry by doing something like this: `bash -c "unity --restart & gcalctool & gksu apt-get update"`. Tune in next week to find out how to get the perfect crackling on belly of pork.

Comment: oh wow, nice... even tough nothing in the answer is actually wrong, let the user and me do their things the way they find best? some ppl havent really been using linux for that much time and are trying to learn. there are ways to say things without crossing the arogance line.